# How to change between Celsius and Fahrenheit in dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

I would like to know if there is a way to rescale data after it's been uploaded to the browser for display in dygraphs. Typical example is to change temperature scale between Celsius and Fahrenheit.
My tables can be pretty big (which by the way dygraphs handle very well once it's uploaded) so I would rather not have to upload the data twice.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You could try some hacks to do the conversion during data formatting using `axes: { y: { valueFormatter, axisLabelFormatter } }`, but this would give odd y-axis ticks and gridlines (they'd be at nice values in Celsius, but formatted in Fahrenheit).

Better to load the data into a JavaScript array once, then alter that when you pass it to dygraphs. Schematically:

```js
var dataCelsius = fetchData();  // Load data
var g = new Dygraph(div, dataCelsius, {...});  // Render Celsius chart
var dataFahrenheit = convertToFahrenheit(dataCelsius);
g.updateOptions({file: dataFahrenheit});  // Change chart to Fahrenheit
```

You can read more about the format of JavaScript array dygraphs expects [here](http://dygraphs.com/data.html).

Comment: thank you for the pointer, looks like it would do what I want.